# Running a Telnet session from VBA

Tags: vba, ftp, excel, telnet

I have a VBA library that does FTP, I'd like to do telnet as well. At the moment I'm shelling out to a Perl script that does the telnet based on a text file, but I'd like to drive the telnet connection natively from within the VBA. Does anyone have any source for this? I don't want to use an add-in, I need the code to be self-contained.

Comment: Asking for code usually doesn't work here. How about you show us what you have done and we will help you make it work or make it better. Also, it would be helpful if you give reference to the Perl script and VBA FTP library.

Comment: Agreed, which is why I answered it. But it's usually better to have more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. My existing VBA FTP code is here: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/35435157/ftp-file-size-from-wininet.aspx

Comment: Sorry, that last link only has a small fragment of the code, here's a link to the full thing: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/ftp-file-size-wininet-t3932684.html

Comment: @PhilHibbs: without the MS Winsock control you're stuck with SendKeys, see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

If you can [use the MS WinSock control](http://objectmix.com/basic-visual/193239-simple-telnet-client-using-winsock-vb6.html) (also see [using winsock in VBA](http://programmersheaven.com/discussion/260724/using-winsock-in-vba))

More resources:

[MSDN Library: Using the Winsock Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733709%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

[(Visual Basic) Winsock Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa228119%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

if not, you could use **cmd.exe** and `SendKeys` perhaps:

Disclaimer: I copied the below code from the second of the links below, and modified it slightly for VBA.

```
sub telNETScript()
On Error Resume Next
Dim WshShell as object

set WshShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.run "cmd.exe"
WScript.Sleep 1000

'Send commands to the window as needed - IP and commands need to be customized
'Step 1 - Telnet to remote IP'
WshShell.SendKeys "telnet xx.xx.xx.73 9999"
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000

'Step 2 - Issue Commands with pauses'
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "5"
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000

'Step 3 - Exit Command Window
WshShell.SendKeys "exit"
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Quit

end sub
```

`SendKeys` is not the best or most reliable solution, but it was all I could find when I did this 12 years ago in my last job.

More info:

[Telnet & Excel - Microsoft.excel.programming](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.excel.programming/2N1e2-imMpI)

[How to automate Telnet commands using VBScript](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/automate-telnet-commands-vb-script/)