# Connecting UNIX through VB and return the results for the commands fired in a variable

Tags: vba, unix

I tried connecting UNIX from visual basic but unable create a connection object like we can do with other programming Languages like Java/python.
I tried some commands like Call Shell etc but really not getting anywhere closer .
please point to the right direction with this issue .

Thanks in Advance :>

Comment: Do you mean you want to use VBA to control a session on a UNIX server?  It's not exactly the tool I would recommend for the job.  Please show what code you have written, and define clearly the goal you have, so that help can be useful.

Comment: It is unclear from your post what you mean by "create a connection object". If you are doing a simple telnet into the UNIX box, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337527/running-a-telnet-session-from-vba OTOH, if you are making an SSH connection, this post might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422938/how-to-run-python-function-in-unix-server-using-excel-vba

Comment: Hi All.....what i am trying to do here is connect to unix machine and then execute my command and then storing the output to a variable.i am very new to VBA .please see if there are any issues with the snippet below:                                                                                                  Public Sub connect_n_execute()
    Dim ssh As New SSHWrapper
    Call ssh.InitConnection("xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx", "my_user", "my_password")
    ssh.Prompt = "$"
    Debug.Print ssh.Excute("ls -l")
    Debug.Print ssh.Excute("exit")
End Sub

Comment: i have installed SharpSShWrapper.msi and the error i am  getting is --"user-defined type not defined"