# Password is not read while executing password change command using writeline in shell

Tags: vba, ssh, putty, plink, console.writeline

I have a code by which I open `plink` for SSH connection using shell command where I can run any command by `StdIn.Writeline` method except password change command. If I run a change password command I am unable to input the password by `StdIn.Writeline` method. The command is like `set usr pwd`. This command gets executed perfectly and after it executes it asks for "Enter Current Password". Here the `WriteLine` method fails to input the password.

Below is the example of the code and ouput:

```
Run = filename & " " & strCompAddress & " -P " & strServerPOrt & " -l " & strServerUser & " -pw " & strServerPassword
Set osh = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set oEx = osh.exec(Run)

oEx.StdIn.WriteLine "command 1" 'This command runs fine'
oEx.StdIn.WriteLine "command 2" 'This command runs fine'
oEx.StdIn.WriteLine "command 3" 'This command runs fine'
oEx.StdIn.WriteLine "set usr wd" 'This command runs fine'
oEx.StdIn.WriteLine "current_pwd" 'This doesn't input the password and it stucks here  
oEx.StdIn.WriteLine "new_pwd"
oEx.StdIn.WriteLine "new_pwd"
oEx.StdIn.WriteLine "exit"
```

Output is like with lots of escape sequence commands.

```
command 1 
command 2
command 3
set usr pwd
current_pwd
new_pwd
new_pwd
exit

Command 1
result
ok

command 2
result 
ok

command 3
result
ok
set usr pwd
Enter Current Password:
```

Comment: Which language is this? You have 3 different ones tagged. vb.net <> vba <> vbscript.

Comment: The password prompt obviously doesn't read from `StdIn`. For further help please provide more information about the remote system and the actual command you're running.

Comment: Comintern - it is vba

 @AnsgarWiechers Remote system is a modified version of Linux box, and the actual command is "set user password" after executing this command Enter Current Password: prompt comes up and after entering the password Enter New Password prompt is displayed and the Re-enter New Password prompt is displayed

Comment: I'd if it's a remote Linux machine, I'd suggest using Telnet instead.  [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5337527/4088852) should get you started.

Comment: @Comintern Using unsecured telnet protocol to change a password? How can you possibly recommend such non-sense?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - Fair enough, but only marginally more nonsensical than changing *any* password via VBA (or any scripting language for that matter). Regardless of the method, the real answer is *"Make sure the server admin is happy with, what you are trying to do."*

Comment: If we can have scripts to change password through bash, then I don;t see the point in discussing why vba.

Answer (score 2):

The command `set user password` (or whatever it is) is possibly built to read the password from terminal only, not from a standard input. This is a common security feature to avoid exactly this kind of automatic password change.

Try forcing an interactive/terminal mode using the Plink command-line [switch `-t`](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-pty).

This will make the Plink input be redirected to a virtual terminal and can make your command happy.

---

*Make sure the server admin is happy with, what you are trying to do.*

Comment: Thank you Martin! finally someone here tried to provide  constructive answer on this query, otherwise I  got vague responses.  Unfortunately switch `-t` didn't work. Also regarding the admin being happy with what I am doing, I am the admin for this lab and I am trying it on a test lab :)